# how to add custom phtml file on the configurable product page on magento 2

Tags: php, module, magento2

i am creating a custom module and i want to include a custom phtml file above the attributes on the configurable product page...

[Click here to see the requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Azv.png)

Please take a look on the module files i have created and what i have done after some google search -

- **etc/di.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" type="Bay20\WarehouseConfigurable\Block\Rewrite\Product\View" />  
</config>
```

- **view/frontened/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <attribute name="class" value="page-product-configurable"/>
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper">
                <block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
            </referenceBlock>
            
        </body>
```

- **view/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml**

```html
 <?php
    
    /** @var $block \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable*/
    //$_product    = $block->getProduct();
    //$_attributes = $block->decorateArray($block->getAllowAttributes());
    
    ?>
    
    <p>Hello there</p>
```

but i am not able to get the file on configurable product view page, What's wrong i am doing, please let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved by this way.

> view/frontened/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
        <block after="product.info.price" class="Test\Mymodule\Block\Posts" name="extra" template="Test_Mymodule::extra.phtml" /> 
    </referenceBlock>        
</body>
```

> view/templates/extra.phtml

```
<?php echo "<p>Extra Block</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

***create file as***

> ***app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml***

***file: catalog_product_view.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" after="product.info.price" 
            as="custom"
                template="Vendor_Module::product/view/custom.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

***in PHTML file***

> ***app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/cusrom.phtml***

```
<div class='custom-box'>
    <span class="custom">
            hii from custom.phtml file
    </span>
</div>
```